# Geb Groovy Test: How to close current tab without closing browser?

Tags: testing, groovy, geb

I tried:

```java
$('body') << Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "w") -
```

```java
driver.close()
```

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"w")
```

this is the code for the test:

```
    def "scrape"() {
    when:
    ScrapeTestPage page = to ScrapeTestPage

    then:

    $("input", name: "search").value("test")
    $("button", type: "submit").click()
    
    $('td a', 0).click() //this opens a new tab

    DetailsPage page1 = to DetailsPage

    println "test"
    //now I'd like to close that tab without closing the first one


}
```

I tried wrapping the new tab in withNewWindow but it throws an error:

withNewWindow({$('td a', 0).click()}){}
|
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected "handle" to be a string, got [object Undefined] undefined

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more specific when you are asking questions here and always supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just small code snippets. That would make your problem reproducible and yield better answers for your own benefit. Thank you. As for your question: Did you actually read the Book of Geb, for instance [this section](https://gebish.org/manual/3.3/#already-opened-windows)? What you are doing is using Selenium style, not Geb style. You do not need to emulate user keyboard interaction in order to close a window.

Comment: Thanks. I tried  withNewWindow({ $('a').click() }) {...} but it throws an error: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected "handle" to be a string, got [object Undefined] undefined

Comment: Which Geb, Selenium, Spock, Groovy, Java versions? What does the HTML page look like (source code or link, if public)? What does the whole Geb specification look like (full class incl. imports, details page? What is `handle`? You do not even show the exact `withNewWindow` command (what is inside?). Please learn why an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the right way to ask questions and how it helps you to get better and quicker answers. Thank you. Just imagine for a moment, I asked you like you asked me. Could you solve the problem with the amount of information given here?

Comment: You're right sorry about that. It ended up being a bug with the Firefox driver I think. withNewWindow command now works as it should in Chrome driver. Thanks for your help